# Finding a obfuscated assembly from a list in powershell

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of dlls in which some of them are already obfuscated. Since they have to be in the same folder i need to skip the assemblies which are already obfuscated.

Presently i'm doing something like this which re-obfuscate.

```
if exist "bin\*.dll" %dotfuscate.bat% bin\*.dll
```

Two ways to deal with this:

1. Name the dlls to exclude
2. Check the list and ignore the obfuscated dlls.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

put your already handled dll names into a file like Exclude.lst and with the following batch every newly processed dll will be appended to that file provided the called batch does not return an errorlevel.

```
Pushd ".\bin"
Set "Excl=X:\Where\ever\Exclude.lst"
For /f %%A in (
  'Dir /B *.dll ^|Findstr /i /V /G:"%Excl%'
) Do Call %dotfuscate.bat% %%~nxA && Echo:%%~nxA >>"%Excl%"
```

Findstr /v outputs lines which none of the exclude file entries matched.

Comment: There is a restriction and I can not put the exclude dll's into a separate folder. All the dlls are into one folder and then i  need to exclude couple of them from that folder.

Comment: In which way does the above batch hinder you in that?